# Modal View Controller crash

Tags: iphone, ios, view, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have three views inside a scroll view. I've added them via the following code;

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:[aViewController view]];
```

When I scroll the view I want to present a modal view controller with its own navigation controller, however this causes a crash. Here's the code I'm using to show the modal view

```
    MyVC *vc = [[MyVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC" bundle:nil];
self.navController.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
self.navController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:vc];
[vc release];
[self presentModalViewController:self.navController animated:YES];
```

And the crash I get is:**erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempting to begin a modal transition from  to  while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current transition has completed'**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Adding a view controller's view directly as a subview is not a good practice. View controllers are meant to be presented, pushed, etc., by appropriate container view controllers so that they, themselves, can manage their views. Pulling views out directly can often lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cann't present current navigation controller. Present instead your `MyVC` viewcontroller

```
MyVC *vc = [[MyVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC" bundle:nil];
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal; [self
presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES]; 
[vc release];
```

---

You can also create a new hierarchy of view controllers, push them to a new navigation controller and present it.

Comment: You can, that's the way to get a nav controller on a modal view, I have done it before. But I just don't get the error in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be trying to present a view controller's navigation controller from within itself. Instead, create a new navigation controller for your modal view controller:

```
MyVC *vc = [[MyVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
[vc release];
```